# Change the direction an element "moves towards" when getting smaller

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

Firstly, I apologize for the horrible title but this is probably why I can't find the answer on my own.

I'm practicing some CSS animations and I want the `form` element to go from `100px -> 0` in height but I want it to do this from TOP to BOTTOM. Instead by default, it goes from BOTTOM to TOP.

So how do I change where an element decides to "close" on its self?

```js
const form   = document.querySelector('form');
const submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
const div    = document.querySelector('div');

submit.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  form.classList.add('height');
  /* div.classList.add('div--animate'); */
});
```

```css
form {
  /* background: lightblue; */
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  transition: height .15s linear, width .15s linear;
  width: 400px;
}

.height {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="name">
  <input type="text" placeholder="email">
  <input class="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Easiest way I can propose is to place your form with `position: relative;` inside a relative container and use `bottom: 0;` to keep it stuck there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider scale transformation and you adjust transform-origin to decide where your element should go. You can also keep the width/height if needed but add a delay to them so they change when the scale end.

```js
const form   = document.querySelector('form');
const submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
const div    = document.querySelector('div');

submit.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  form.classList.add('height');
});
```

```css
form {
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform .15s linear,height 0s .15s linear,width 0s .15s linear;
  transform-origin:bottom right; /* center | top right | left | ...*/
  width: 400px;
}

.height {
  width:0;
  height:0;
  transform:scale(0);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="name">
  <input type="text" placeholder="email">
  <input class="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Great answer, did not know you could reference a transition value that was not in the same class name, ie. `transition: transform .15s...` in the `form` selector.

Comment: @BrandonBenefield yes you can, as even if you don't set it there will be a default value ;) so you can put all the property within transition without the need to define them [of course it may not work as some properties need default values]

Comment: What's the advantage of having the width/height when using `scale`? I can't visually see a difference, is there something going on that I don't know about?

Comment: @BrandonBenefield visually there is no difference BUT making the height width to 0 will remove the element from the flow and it won't take space, but using only scale the space of the element will remain ... of course you are not obliged to keep height/width transition if you only need a visual effect

Comment: Nope you are absolutely correct, thanks for the advice.